# How to automatically create ObjectID for children in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, json.net

I have a Service1 that creates a `JObject`. Then i have Service2 which inserts that JObject into mongo DB.

**Service1**

```
var doc = GetDocument();
var jDoc = new JObject(
                    new JProperty("_id", doc.DocumentID),
                    new JProperty("url", doc.DocumentLink),                   
                    new JProperty("cost", null),
                    new JProperty("context", new JObject(
                        new JProperty("endTime", null),
                        new JProperty("startTime", doc.DocumentCreated))),                   
                    new JProperty("tasks", new JObject(
                        new JProperty("phase", "completed"),                        
                        new JProperty("initialTask", new JObject(                              
                                new JProperty("name",doc.DocumentName),
                                new JProperty("input", "someinput"))))));
```

Then im passing this jObject to Service2 which inserts it into mongoDB

**Service2**

```
     public async Task Create(JObject jDoc)
     {
            var collection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("units");
            var bDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(jDoc.ToString());
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(bDoc);
        }
    }
```

Service1 creates `_id` for the root document element. I was expecting when Service2 inserts document into mongoDb it will automatically creates `_id` for child properties like `context`, `tasks` and `initialTask` however its not creating `_id` for childrens.

**Questions**
1> How do i automatially create `_id` for all children?
2> In case we cannot create `_id` automatically, and only option is to create `_id` is Service1 then can we create ObjectID in Service1 without having reference to `MongoDB.Deriver`.  Note that only Service2 has reference to `MongoDB.Driver`. Service1 does not have reference to `MongoDB.Driver`.
i want `_id` of the children in the following format

```
"_id" : ObjectId("559b3cc8bf13a6740d7d50b0")
```

Comment: may be because it's clashing with the _id field that you already have in service 1. You can try renaming and then create again.

Comment: You should really try modeling your documents with classes not JObject's

Answer (score 0):

Without using a document object as a parameter, I didn't find a good solution to your problem.

1) Automatically generating `_id` values of type `ObjectId` is possible if you use attributes on properties in a document object. You can avoid referencing the MongoDB library in Service1 by using a common interface or a wrapper class with the attributes. If this doesn't appeal to you, you can try using `SetOnInsert`; however, this would again require that you pass information about the structure of the `JObject` to the `Create` method.

2) If you still want to use `JObject`, you can either use find/replace (possibly using a regex) or create a custom datatype for the `_id` properties and create a custom serializer. The following does work as expected:

```
string json = "{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"559b3cc8bf13a6740d7d50b0\") }";
BsonDocument bDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(json);
```